# How to set a TextView color look as shown in this picture?

Tags: android, textview

I used

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml())
```

but it only changed the color of the last letter

[image]

Comment: please share your code, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spannable

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(YOUR_TEXT);

spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), text.length(), (text + Your_textviewlength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set your colour:

```
setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
yourTextView.setTextColor(color);
```

Or, in your case:`yourTextView.setTextColor(0xffbdbdbd);`